# $a, b$ are the integer part and decimal fraction of $\sqrt7$ find integer part of $\frac{a}{b}$

Tags: integers, square-numbers

> $a, b$ are the integer part and decimal fraction of $\sqrt7$
>
> find integer part of $\frac{a}{b}$

using calculator :
$\sqrt 7$ = 2.645

$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{2}{0.6} = \frac{20}{6} = 3.333$
integer part of $\frac{a}{b} = 3$

how to do it without calculator? if i don't know $\sqrt7$ part

Comment: Be careful:
$$
\frac{2}{0.645} \neq 3.333
$$

Comment: Is "decimal fraction of a number" another name for the fractional part (i.e., is it used in some book), or did you just make that up?

Comment: it is from a book, why?

Comment: @MattiP. it is $ \frac{2}{0.645}$ or $ \frac{2}{0.6}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$ 2.5<\sqrt 7<3$$

$$ \frac {a}{b} = \frac {2}{\sqrt 7 -2} = \frac {2(\sqrt 7+2)}{3}$$

$$3= \frac {2( 2.5+2)}{3} <        \frac {2(\sqrt 7+2)}{3} <\frac {2( 3+2)}{3}<4$$

Thus the integer part of $\frac {2}{\sqrt 7 -2}$ is $3$

Answer (score 2):

My solution without a calculator:
Since $2^2 = 4$ and $3^2=9$, we know that $\sqrt{7} = 2 +b $ and therefore
$$
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{2}{b} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{7}-2} = \frac{2}{(\sqrt{7}-2)} \frac{(\sqrt{7}+2)}{(\sqrt{7}+2)} = \frac{2(\sqrt{7}+2)}{7-4} = \frac{2}{3} \left(\sqrt{7}+2 \right)
$$
And since $2 < \sqrt{7} < 3$, we know that (plugging these into the expression)
$$
\frac{8}{3} < \frac{2}{3} \left(\sqrt{7}+2 \right) < \frac{10}{3}
$$
which indicates that the integer part of $a/b$ is $3$.

**Edit**: the lower bound is not tight enough. But this can be fixed.

First observation:
$
4\cdot 7 = 28 > 25 \Rightarrow \sqrt{7}> \frac{5}{2}
$

Then: 
$$
\left[ \frac{2}{3}\left( \sqrt{7}+2 \right) \right]^2 = \frac{4}{9} (11+4 \sqrt{7}) > \frac{4}{9} (11+4 \cdot \frac{5}{2}) = \frac{4}{9}\cdot 21 = \frac{28}{3}> \frac{27}{3} = 9
$$
so therefore $\frac{2}{3} \left(\sqrt{7}+2 \right) > 3$.

Comment: This answer is incomplete since the lower bound isn't sharp enough. This is covered by the other answers. You've correctly shown that $2.67<a/b<3.33$ but this gives us two cases. Either $2.67<a/b<3$, in which case $\lfloor a/b \rfloor = 2$ *or* $3\leq a/b<3.33$, in which case $\lfloor a/b \rfloor = 3$. You need to prove that the lower bound is at least $3$.

Comment: Good job fixing the bound. Nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

$4<7<9$, so the integer part is $a=2$ and thus $b=\sqrt7-2=\frac3{\sqrt7+2}$. With that
$$
\frac ab=\frac{2(\sqrt7+2)}3
$$
Now also $25<4\cdot 7=28<36$, so that one can further simplify
$$
...=\frac{4+5}3+\frac{\sqrt{28}-5}3=3+\frac1{\sqrt{28}+5}
$$
Here you can again see what the integer part is.

Comment: I think this skips a few steps that might confuse the OP. It might be good if you wrote out the algebraic rearrangement: $2(\sqrt{7}+2)=2\sqrt{7}+4=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{7}+4=\sqrt{28}+4+(5-5)$ because imo it's not exactly obvious. Also your inequality $25<27<36$ was presumably meant to read $28$.

Comment: @Jam : If it is expected that OP finds an answer on his own, then I can expect that they can fill in some basic arithmetic and algebraic manipulations.

Comment: $25< 4.7 < 36$ where this come from?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter : Please tune your lenses, in the answer there is a multiplication dot, not a decimal sign.

Comment: yes. $25 < 4\cdot7 < 36$ where does it come from? i like your answer, just a little bit confused at the ending part

Comment: @Lifeforbetter To determine the integers around $2\sqrt7=\sqrt{28}$, check the squares sequence, you should know the squares up to 100. You got another answer that used the squares up to 1000 to enclose $10\sqrt{7}=\sqrt{700}$. In principle you could use any other rational approximation, like the one following from $3\sqrt7=\sqrt{63}=8\sqrt{1-\frac1{64}}\in[8-\frac18,8]$.

Answer (score 1):

$2.6^2=6.76<7<7.29=2.7^2.$

So $a=2$ and $0.6<b<0.7.$

So $4>10/3=2/0.6>a/b>2/0.7=20/7>2.$

So the integer part of $a/b$ is $2$ or $3.$

Now $$3\le a/b\iff 3b\le a\iff  3b\le 2 \iff b\le 2/3 \iff$$ $$\iff  \sqrt 7=a+b=2+b\le 2+2/3=8/3\iff$$ $$\iff 7\le (8/3)^2=64/9 =7+1/9.$$ Since we used "$\iff$" throughout, and since it is true that $7\le (8/3)^2,$ therefore $3\le a/b.$ And we already have $a/b<4$. So we have $$3\le a/b<4.$$